# Limit without De L'Hospital: $\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\sin x-1}{2x-\pi}$

Tags: calculus, limits, education, limits-without-lhopital

We must to calculate $$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\sin x-1}{2x-\pi}.$$
It is very simple with l'Hospital's rule that the limit is zero. But what would happen if I didn't use l'Hospital's rule?

In fact if $t=x-\frac{\pi}2$ we have $x=t+\frac{\pi}2$ hence

$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2} \frac{\sin x-1}{2x-\pi}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin \left(t+\frac{\pi}2\right)-\sin\frac{\pi}2}{2t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2\sin\left(t+\pi\right)\cos t}{2t}=$$$$-\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t\cos t}{t}=1$$
that is not $0$. What am I doing wrong? Any trivial mistakes?

Comment: $\sin(t+\frac{\pi}{2})-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) \ne 2\sin(t+\pi)\cos(t)$. For instance, $t=\pi/2$.

Comment: $\sin \left(t+\frac{\pi}2\right)-\sin\frac{\pi}{2}=2\cos(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2})\sin \frac{t}{2}$

Comment: Please note $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ is the _definition_ of $f^\prime(a)$; it **does not** use the forbidden rule. Now take $a:=\frac12\pi,\,f(x):=\frac12\sin x$.

Comment: @J.G. Hiiiiiii :-). Why, please, do you taken $a:=\frac12\pi,\,f(x):=\frac12\sin x$? Yes you are right.

Comment: Because you were attempting to say "I'm not allowed to use $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f^\prime(a)}{g^\prime(a)}$ for arbitrary $g$", but it's important to understand _linear_ g are a trivial special case.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I wanted to use the derivative of the denominator and the derivative of the denominator having $\cos x/2$ and for the variable tending to pi/2 I should get 0 with De The Hospital's rule.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Rest assured. I'm not very lucid sorry. I am using and use the translator a lot. I prefer the answers :-) but right now I can not understand. Excuse me.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes :-)))) with the Hospital's rule. Please, can you edit my question. I am with a very low level in English language.

Comment: How did you get $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin \left(t+\frac{\pi}2\right)-\sin\frac{\pi}2}{2t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2\sin\left(t+\pi\right)\cos t}{2t}$$ ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I have reversed in my mind the prostapheresis formulas between the sum and difference of sines.

Comment: But using that formula, doesn't $\ \sin\left(t + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 2\sin\left( \frac{1}{2} t\right) \cos \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( t+ \pi \right) \right)\ ?\ $ I don't see how you got $\ 2\sin(t+\pi)\cos t\ .$

Comment: @AdamRubinson I have used $\sin\alpha-\sin\beta=2\,\sin \frac {\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos \frac {\alpha-\beta}{2}$ :-(((((((((

Comment: That's incorrect. It's $\ \sin\alpha - \sin \beta = 2 \cos \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \sin\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We must to calculate $$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\sin x-1}{2x-\pi}$$

If we use a change of variables $\ h = x - \frac{\pi}{2},\ $then this becomes:

$$\lim_{h\to \ 0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + h\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{2h}$$

$$\overset{(*)}{=}\frac{1}{2}\ f'\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right),$$

where $\ f(x) = \sin(x).\ $ All we have done at $\ (*)\ $is use the definition of $\ f'(x).$

But $\ f'\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0,\ $ and therefore the answer is $\ \frac{1}{2} \times 0 = 0.$

$$$$

Also, from the comments, you went wrong here:

> $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin
> \left(t+\frac{\pi}2\right)-\sin\frac{\pi}2}{2t}=\lim_{t\to
> 0}\frac{2\sin\left(t+\pi\right)\cos t}{2t}$$

This is incorrect. The correct formula is:

$\ \sin\alpha - \sin \beta = 2 \cos \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \sin\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2},\ $ which would get you:

$\ \sin\left(t + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 2\cos \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( t+ \pi \right)\right)\sin\left( \frac{1}{2} t\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to rewrite it is
$$ \frac{\sin(t + \pi/2) - 1}{2t} = \frac{\sin t\cos(\pi/2) + \sin(\pi/2)\cos t - 1}{2t} = \frac{\cos t - 1}{2t}. $$